# How to implement a graphical logic flow in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I want to create a WPF application that allows the user to create graphical logic flows similar to Visio.  The end goal is to use this as a way for users to write simple scripts without the need to write any scripting code.  I need to be able to represent two basic elements: Boolean decision (if then else) and an action block.  Thy need to be able to be connected in some way like arrows to designate process flow direction.

I realize there is probably no solution exactly like this available, but are there any examples out there for at least a simple graphical flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a series of four articles over on CodeProject which may be what you are looking for:

[WPF Diagram Designer (including source)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4)

This above is the final part in the series, the article links to the three earlier parts. Article is using .NET 3.5, however I believe the changes between .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 in WPF are minimal (assuming you are going to be developing in .NET 4.0).

Comment: +1 Good reference, i used the same to learn how to do it in wpf.